# How to get list element to cover the entire height - CSS IE8 list element height

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a border around a menu. The border is having rounded corners and I have to support all kinds of browsers (ie7 / ie8 ..) so I'm trying to use pictures to draw the entire border around the menu.

How can I get leftBorder and rightBorder to cover the entire height (2 black dots in the example) ? Look at the ex below.

http://jsfiddle.net/3367E/14/

The menu is having dynamic height so I can't just set one static height!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the standard CSS `border` property?

Comment: No, then I don't get the corners right, because of the dynmic height of the list.

Comment: How are you rounding the corners?

Comment: I'm not planing to "rounding" the corners, but copy the corners out of a picture and paste it into each corner in the example. And then do the same with the straight lines .

Comment: Wouldn't a property like border-radius be better for that?

Comment: If I lived in a perfect world and didn't have to support old IE . IE8 browser do not support border radius

Comment: Tell me why. In one of my client websites I use a system like this.  Nobody complains. (I'm not trying to be stubborn, I'm genuinely wondering why you need to use this method).

Comment: Since I'm using IE8 I cant use fancy stuff like CSS3. I'm trying to get nice border around a menu using pictures. If you see my axample I have 8 images to draw the entire border. Since the list inside the menu is dynamicly added with different numbers of elements inside, the height gets different. I only got this to work by using javascript.